# I have a Facebook app and Facebook has automatically created a Fan Page automatically (separate from the app page)

Tags: facebook

Has anyone experienced this? Facebook says the Fan Page is for admin purposes (view insights, etc.) but the page itself seems to have limited functionality. I can't edit it like a normal Page and the "About" and "Description" fields were populated automatically but are duplicates of each other. Again, I can't find a way to edit the fields without messing up the actual App description. What can I do?

Comment: I am also finding this, but I don't have an app. The page was created automatically by clicking the 'like' button on a web page which I am an admin of, and now I can't seem to edit the page. Did you find a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much this will help but, I'm pretty sure I merged my app fan page with my regular fan page earlier, and it wreaked havoc on everything. If you are given the opportunity to do that anywhere, don't, because you can't reverse it...